# Show election voting privilege notice next to its button

Tags: feature-request, design, election, popups

Clicking on one of the buttons in [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/election) election, I saw this notice pop up:

[image]

But it showed *way* down here!

[image]

If my scrollbar had been any farther up the page, I wouldn't have seen that.  Can we make the notice pop out next to the button, to avoid mistakes like this?  I also don't know why this would be by design; the "voting on comments on deleted posts" notice doesn't popup near the answer icon, for instance.

Or, make it like the Vote Down privilege dropdown:

[image]